# There's a way to template a variable in ansible

Tags: templates, variables, ansible, jinja2

```
applications:
  appA:
    someDB:
      enable: true
      datadir: '/var/lib/postgresql/11/appA'

  appB:
    someDB:
      enable: true
      datadir: '/var/lib/postgresql/11/appB'

- ansible.builtin.set_fact:
    clusters: "{{ clusters + [ item ] }}"
  when: applications.{{ item }}.someDB.enable
  loop:
    - appA
    - appB

- ansible.builtin.shell: |
    pg_createcluster \
      -d {{ aplications.item.someDB.datadir }}
  when: item == 'appA'
  loop: "{{ clusters }}"
```

Is there a simple way to make ansible do substitutions inside a var ? Like some precedence operand.

In the loop: item == appA

so, {{ aplications.item.someDB.datadir }} is like this {{ aplications.appA.someDB.datadir }}, and autmatocally is its content is: '/var/lib/postgresql/11/appA' and so on.

Probably I'm using the wrong approach, but seems reasonable to me do that.

Thank's for any help.

Answer (score 1):

The `applications` variable can be flattened, so it will be easier to set the conditions for the task

```yaml
applications:
  - name: appA
    someDB:
      enable: true
      datadir: '/var/lib/postgresql/11/appA'

  - name: appB
    someDB:
      enable: true
      datadir: '/var/lib/postgresql/11/appB'

- name: Create PG cluster
  ansible.builtin.shell: >
    pg_createcluster
      -d {{ item.someDB.datadir }}
  when:
    - item.name == 'appA'
    - item.someDB.enable
  loop: "{{ applications }}"
```

Some comments:

- Adding a unique `name` to the task will make it easier to debug your playbooks, specially when you have a long playbook or role
- using `>` in `shell` will take care to collapse the instructions as a single line, so you won't need the slash
- Usually to create a postgress database, you would prefer to use the [postgresql_db](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/community/postgresql/postgresql_db_module.html) Ansible module; the `-d <directory>` is preferred to be set in the configuration file, so you wouldn't need it as an argument.

Answer (score 1):

Create the list of enabled *clusters*

```yaml
  clusters: "{{ applications|dict2items|
                json_query('[?value.someDB.enable].key') }}"
```

gives

```yaml
  clusters:
  - appA
  - appB
```

Then, the task below creates the run-strings you want

```yaml
    - debug:
        msg: "pg_createcluster -d {{ applications[item].someDB.datadir }}"
      loop: "{{ clusters }}"
```

gives (abridged)

```yaml
  msg: pg_createcluster -d /var/lib/postgresql/11/appA
  msg: pg_createcluster -d /var/lib/postgresql/11/appB
```

---

Example of a complete playbook for testing

```yaml
- hosts: localhost

  vars:

    applications:
      appA:
        someDB:
          enable: true
          datadir: '/var/lib/postgresql/11/appA'
      appB:
        someDB:
          enable: true
          datadir: '/var/lib/postgresql/11/appB'

    clusters: "{{ applications|dict2items|
                  json_query('[?value.someDB.enable].key') }}"

  tasks:

    - debug:
        var: clusters

    - debug:
        msg: "pg_createcluster -d {{ applications[item].someDB.datadir }}"
      loop: "{{ clusters }}"
```

---

Notes:

- You can get both the key and the value by substitution

```yaml
    - debug:
        msg: "{{ _key }}: {{ _val }}"
      loop:
        - appA
        - appB
      when: applications[item].someDB.enable
      vars:
        _key: "applications.{{ item }}.someDB.datadir"
        _val: "{{ applications[item].someDB.datadir }}"
```

gives (abridged)

```yaml
  msg: 'applications.appA.someDB.datadir: /var/lib/postgresql/11/appA'
  msg: 'applications.appB.someDB.datadir: /var/lib/postgresql/11/appB'
```

- Create a dictionary to simplify the searching

```yaml
  app_datadir: "{{ dict(applications|dict2items|
                        json_query('[].[key, value.someDB.datadir]')) }}"
```

gives

```yaml
  app_datadir:
    appA: /var/lib/postgresql/11/appA
    appB: /var/lib/postgresql/11/appB
```

Use this dictionary *"to make Ansible do substitutions"*. For example,

```yaml
    - debug:
        msg: "applications.{{ item }}.someDB.datadir: {{ app_datadir[item] }}"
      loop:
        - appA
        - appB
```

gives (abridged)

```yaml
  msg: 'applications.appA.someDB.datadir: /var/lib/postgresql/11/appA'
  msg: 'applications.appB.someDB.datadir: /var/lib/postgresql/11/appB'
```

---

Example of a complete playbook for testing

```yaml
- hosts: localhost

  vars:

    applications:
      appA:
        someDB:
          enable: true
          datadir: '/var/lib/postgresql/11/appA'
      appB:
        someDB:
          enable: true
          datadir: '/var/lib/postgresql/11/appB'

    app_datadir: "{{ dict(applications|dict2items|
                          json_query('[].[key, value.someDB.datadir]')) }}"

  tasks:

    - debug:
        var: app_datadir

    - debug:
        msg: "applications.{{ item }}.someDB.datadir: {{ app_datadir[item] }}"
      loop:
        - appA
        - appB
```

---

- You can also create the dictionary *app_enable*

```yaml
    app_enable: "{{ dict(applications|dict2items|
                         json_query('[].[key, value.someDB.enable]')) }}"
```

gives

```yaml
  app_enable:
    appA: true
    appB: true
```

and use it in the condition. For example,

```yaml
    - debug:
        msg: "applications.{{ item }}.someDB.datadir: {{ app_datadir[item] }}"
      loop:
        - appA
        - appB
      when: app_enable[item]
```